Convex set in the upper half-plane of Poincaré.
I am starting to learn Riemannian manifolds and I am reading the book "Convex functions and optimization methods on Riemannian manifolds-Constantin Udristre" on page 100, they define a function $h:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, h( x,y)=-y^2- \ln(y)$  is quasiconvex because the sublevel sets are described by $y\geq y_0$ (convex sets), what is difficult for me to understand is how it defines the sublevel set and its demonstration of convexity, if $\mathbb{H}$ is convex, if the sublevel set is defined as it is a subset of $\mathbb {H}$ could you demonstrate its convexity that way? Or I would have to prove that every two-point geodesic is contained in the set, in this case in its sublevel set.

You are asking several questions at once. Did you try to compute sublevel sets of this monotonic function of one variable? If you cannot do this, then you might not be ready for the material which requires at least some basic knowledge of calculus.
